# How to set FontStyle for some text in a rich text box?

Tags: c#

I have a RichTextBox. I want change fontStyle of selected text without change FontFamily.

I use this code

```
 RTBMain.SelectionFont = new Font(RTBMain.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
```

It is change fontstyle, but my problem is :

When i select a text with change fontfamily, i get error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

beacuse

```
RTBMain.SelectionFont=null
```

For example :

My text is "I have a student "

FontFamily for "a" is "Tahoma"

FontFamily for "student" is "Tango"

Then i select "a student" : FontFamily for this is null.

But when i select "a" or "student" : font family not is null.

Comment: which you event your using to set the selectionfont?

Comment: I use a button for change FontStyle. Plz see my edit .

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solved it? :-?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(RTBMain.SelectionFont != null)
{
 RTBMain.SelectionFont = new Font(RTBMain.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

or

```
if (RTBMain.SelectionLength > 0)
{
 RTBMain.SelectionFont = new Font(RTBMain.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

**[REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

```
private void ToggleBold()
{
 if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont != null)
 {
  System.Drawing.Font currentFont = richTextBox1.SelectionFont;
  System.Drawing.FontStyle newFontStyle;

  if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
  {
     newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
  }
  else
  {
     newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
  }

  richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(
     currentFont.FontFamily, 
     currentFont.Size, 
     newFontStyle
  );
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, `SelectionLength >0` but , FontFamily is null beacuse My SelectetionText have multy FontFamily.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
richTextBox1.Find("Text", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);

richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

You need to select the text you want to change format, first.

And `SelectionFont` cannot be two fonts at the same time.